# Display only posts with thumbnails

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails, meta-query

I'm trying to have a WP theme display only posts that have a thumbnail.

Below is the code of the file that shows some posts on the frontpage. I've already tried to change the code (please see the //added by me start/stop) and from what I've read it should do the trick. However, on the front page, posts without thumbnails are displayed as well.

```
<?php
if ( ! get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_enable_posts_list_section', false ) ) {
    return;
}

$content_ids   = array();
$content_count = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_count', 6 );
$content_type  = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_content_type', 'category' );

if ( in_array( $content_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) {

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $content_count; $i++ ) {
        $content_ids[] = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_content_' . $content_type . '_' . $i );
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => $content_type,
        'post__in'            => array_filter( $content_ids ),
        'orderby'             => 'post__in',
        'posts_per_page'      => absint( $content_count ),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
//added by me start
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
         'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
//added by me stop
    );

} elseif ( $content_type === 'category' ) {
    $cat_content_id = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_content_category' );
    $args           = array(
        'cat'            => $cat_content_id,
        'posts_per_page' => absint( $content_count ),
//added by me start
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
         'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
//added by me stop
    );
} elseif ( $content_type === 'recent' ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'      => absint( $content_count ),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
//added by me start
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
         'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
//added by me stop
    );
}

$args = apply_filters( 'flash_news_posts_list_section_args', $args );

flash_news_render_posts_list_section( $args );

/**
 * Render Posts List Section.
 */
function flash_news_render_posts_list_section( $args ) {
    $section_title = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_title', __( 'Posts List', 'flash-news' ) );
    $button_label  = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_button_label', __( 'View All', 'flash-news' ) );
    $button_link   = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_button_link' );
    $button_link   = ! empty( $button_link ) ? $button_link : '#';
    $tile_style    = get_theme_mod( 'flash_news_posts_list_section_style', 'style-1' );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts()) :
        ?>
        <section id="flash_news_posts_list_section" class="magazine-frontpage-section magazine-small-list-section <?php echo esc_attr( $tile_style ); ?>">
            <?php
            if ( is_customize_preview() ) :
                flash_news_section_link( 'flash_news_posts_list_section' );
            endif;
            ?>
            <div class="ascendoor-wrapper">
                <div class="section-header">
                    <h3 class="section-title"><?php echo esc_html( $section_title ); ?></h3>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $button_link ); ?>" class="mag-view-all-link"><?php echo esc_html( $button_label ); ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="magazine-section-body">
                    <div class="magazine-list-section-wrapper">
                        <?php
                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                            $query->the_post();
                            ?>
                            <div class="mag-post-single has-image list-design">
                                <div class="mag-post-img">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mag-post-detail">
                                    <div class="mag-post-detail-inner">
                                        <div class="mag-post-category">
                                            <?php flash_news_categories_list(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3 class="mag-post-title">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </h3>
                                        <div class="mag-post-meta">
                                            <span class="post-author">
                                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author() ); ?></a>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="post-date">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="far fa-clock"></i><?php echo esc_html( get_the_date() ); ?></a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <?php
    endif;

}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: have you looked at the `pre_get_posts` filter? `WP_Query` does not modify/replace the main query, it creates _new_ additional queries that add extra cost. If you want to change which posts are shown you should modify the main query to use the parameters you prefer, rather than putting those parameters into brand new queries via the `pre_get_posts` filter.

Comment: also this is very likely related to `post__in`, if you're telling WP to fetch a predefined list of IDs why would it apply additional filters to the query on top of that. It might be better to do the check in PHP instead of asking the database to do it, especially if you have a pre-determined list already

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the suggestions. I'm not that skilled. It is not my theme, I'm simply trying to use it. I was hoping for a quick fix, but if I have to start learning about pre_get_posts / post__in I think I'll better use another theme.